# Errors with .BAT files (Syntax)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, batch-file, nginx

I'm developing a web server in C #, but I have some problems with BATCH files that get Apache and MySQL running.
The BATCH that makes NGINX work I could do, but PHP does not start, gives an error of syntax and also need help with it.

**NGINX-START.BAT** (NGINX starts, but PHP does not start and syntax error)

Start Directory: `C:\Users\NETO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MHServer\MHServer\bin\Debug\Server\Files\NGINX`

Target Directory: `C:\Users\NETO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MHServer\MHServer\bin\Debug\` with `Php\php-cgi.exe`

*Error message*: The syntax of the file name, directory name or volume label is incorrect.
The system can not find the path specified.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd \%CD%\
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
cd Nginx
start nginx

set PATH=\Php;%PATH%
\Php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
:exit
```

**Apache-start.bat** (Apache does not start and syntax error)

*Error message:* The syntax of the file name, directory name or volume label is incorrect.
The system can not find the path specified.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd \%CD%\
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
\Apache\bin\Apache.exe
```

**MySQL-start.bat** (MySQL does not start and syntax error)

*Error message:* The syntax of the file name, directory name or volume label is incorrect.
The system can not find the path specified.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd \%CD%\
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
\MySql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=\MySql\my.ini --standalone --console
:exit
```

**Folder Structure** (Folders of programs and files)

- [`C:\MHServer\Apache`] - Apache Path
- [`C:\MHServer\MySql`] - MySQL Path
- [`C:\MHServer\Nginx`] - NGINX Path
- [`C:\MHServer\Php`] - PHP Path

**BAT folder files**

- [`C:\MHServer\Server\Files\Apache`] - Apache BAT Files
- [`C:\MHServer\Server\Files\MySQL`] - MySQL BAT Files
- [`C:\MHServer\Server\Files\NGINX`] - NGINX BAT Files

**File Structure**

- [`/Files/`](http://prntscr.com/1inmcz)
- [`/Files/Apache/`](http://prntscr.com/1inmjc)
- [`/Files/MySQL/`](http://prntscr.com/1inmn5)
- [`/Files/NGINX/`](http://prntscr.com/1inmr4)

I am not very good with BAT files, so I have come to you for help!

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error message(s).

Comment: Please show your complete folder tree.

Comment: /Files/ folder: http://prntscr.com/1inmcz
/Files/Apache/ folder: http://prntscr.com/1inmjc
/Files/MySQL/ folder: http://prntscr.com/1inmn5
/Files/NGINX/ folder: http://prntscr.com/1inmr4

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the backslashes from before the relative directory names.

For example:

```
\Apache\bin\Apache.exe
```

should be

```
Apache\bin\Apache.exe
```

Also, if you want to add your PHP directory to the PATH environmental variable in NGINX-START.BAT, you will need to use the full path, not a relative one.  Something like this will work:

```
set PATH=%CD%\Php;%PATH%
```

Also, what are you trying to do with the `cd \%CD%\`? That should give an error on its own, so remove that from all of the scripts too.

So your first batch file should look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
cd Nginx
start nginx
cd ..
set PATH=%CD%\Php;%PATH%
Php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
:exit
```

Comment: None of their solutions were functional for my problem. I keep getting the same error!

Comment: I edited the above post with a fully edited version of your NGINX-START.bat. Try that out.

Comment: with NGINX-START.BAT you gave me I managed to turn the NGINX correctly, but PHP does not care because it is not in the same directory as the BAT.

Comment: I managed to fix the errors in APACHE-START.BAT and MySQL-START.BAT now just need help even in NGINX-START.BAT

Comment: Where is the PHP directory located? It's not in the Files directory screenshot.

Comment: I managed to make PHP work perfectly, but now would like to help me make the hidden console open.